# Run .exe before windows logon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I´m new here, the problem that I have is with a console application. I was searching and I find that I can run the console application before windows login as a Windows Service, I have tried many processes but I can´t resolve it, some says that I need to add code and others says that I only need add to gpedit.msc, please if someone can help me. This is the code of my program:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            ///Method Begins.

            Console.WriteLine("Please wait, we are recording your access...");
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting with the DataBase");

            PCRegister.PcRegisterSoapClient cliente = new PCRegister.PcRegisterSoapClient();

            cliente.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["username"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"]);

            cliente.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            cliente.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
            Console.WriteLine();

           ///This Method Gets the HOST IP
            Console.Write("Getting your IP");
            Console.WriteLine();
            IPGlobalProperties network = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = network.GetActiveTcpConnections();
            string ipAddress = connections[0].LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString();

            ///This Method Send the HostName to the DataBase and look if exist or not.
            PCRegister.CriteriaDataSet criteriaDataSet = new PCRegister.CriteriaDataSet();

            PCRegister.CriteriaDataSet.CriteriaRow criteriaRow = criteriaDataSet.Criteria.NewCriteriaRow();

            criteriaRow.ColumnName = "HostName";

            criteriaRow.Value = Environment.MachineName;

            criteriaDataSet.Criteria.AddCriteriaRow(criteriaRow);

            criteriaDataSet.Criteria.AcceptChanges();

            PCRegister.PcRegisterListDataSet getList = new PCRegister.PcRegisterListDataSet();
                getList = cliente.GetList(criteriaDataSet);

            Console.WriteLine("Sending Information");

            ///Create a New Full DataSet.
            PCRegister.PcRegisterFullDataSet pcRegisterFullDataSet = new PCRegister.PcRegisterFullDataSet();

            ///Here the Get List will go to Data Base and look if are another HostName with the same name.
            ///If Yes, this will make an update in the Data Base.
            ///If Not, this will insert a new row.
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");    
            if (getList.PcRegisterList.Count > 0)
                {
                    ///Get the PrimaryKey from PcRegisterListDataset that was filled by the GetList.
                    Guid primaryKey = getList.PcRegisterList[0].ComputerID;
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet = cliente.GetByID(primaryKey);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet.PcRegister[0].HostName = criteriaRow.Value;
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet.PcRegister[0].IPAddress = ipAddress;
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet.PcRegister[0].ChangeDate = System.DateTime.Today;
                    Console.WriteLine("HostName:" + Environment.MachineName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your New Host IP: " + ipAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date: " + System.DateTime.Now);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You are already Registred");
                    //Console.WriteLine("You are already registred, press ENTER to exit");
                    cliente.Update(pcRegisterFullDataSet);
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet = cliente.GetNew();
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet.PcRegister[0].HostName = criteriaRow.Value;
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet.PcRegister[0].IPAddress = ipAddress;
                    pcRegisterFullDataSet.PcRegister[0].ChangeDate = System.DateTime.Today;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("HostName: " + criteriaRow.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Host IP: " + ipAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date: " + System.DateTime.Now);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You are already Registred");
                    //Console.WriteLine("You are already registred, press ENTER to exit");
                    cliente.Update(pcRegisterFullDataSet);
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
        }            

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot run a console application before windows login.  You need to create a Windows Service.  [Documentation on MSDN is pretty good](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do you want to execute your script every time a user logs in the windows machine? There are many ways like editing the registry and adding a path to it or using group policy editor. Have a look at this similar post: https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows

Comment: Yeah I need run before Windows Login... but I can use my console for the Windows Service or I need make another thing??

Comment: You could use your code for a windows service, you would just need to create and install the service.  Pss is correct as well, you could run the script from the registry as well.

Comment: what´s the difference if I made the Windows Service or run the script from the registry??

Comment: Do you need to run a script every time a user logs in, or do you need a process that starts when your computer powers up? Depending on which that is you are after the answers are different. In the former case you need to go with the policy/registry path in the latter you need a windows service. Judging from your code you need the former.

Comment: Running from registry will only work once the user has logged into the machine. And this method is just simple. Create an executable from your script and then edit the registry to run this executable every time when user logs in. Edit these keys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices

Comment: @ManuelFdz A service is cleaner in my opinion, but you will lose your console window.  You can use the same code and write to a log, but the user will not see anything displayed on the screen.

Comment: Yes I need before login, so for the articles and the answers from you I thing that Windows Service will work!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not know how to create a windows service? right?
In Professional-Editions of Visual Studio there is a template for creating a Windows serivce.
On [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C) you'll find a Article about creating a basic Windows Service in C#.

I think, in Windows Services you'll have no Console window for your Outputs, but you could write a log file.

Answer (score 0):

you can verify weather your service is available at system configuration start up.

To check that. Go to RUN and type "Msconfig". and make sure that your have checked the application you want to execute.

Comment: But this only works after I bypass the auth of windows... I need before the bypass.

Comment: @ManuelFdz what you are asking for is a Windows Service.

Comment: I´m new in the programming world, I learn C# in my work, I´m Mechatronics Engineer and the lenguages are so different but I want to learn different things and mix it... I thing that Windows Service are the solution for the articles that I read

Comment: @ManuelFdz Cheers everyone is new to everything for the first time! :)